# Jetson Nano Remote Desktop on Global Server

Tags: live-streaming, remote-desktop, nvidia-jetson-nano

I want to know any Service in Nvidia Jetson Nano 2GB Developer Kit for accessing the board Remotely , anywhere , basically on the global Server , not on Local like we do just typing IP

I tried TeamViewer but it crashes , Real VNC is not available in Jetson , any other alternative??